# Where can I connect c wire from adaptor if I don’t have c terminal in my boiler control board

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I was wondering if someone can help, I have an IBC boiler (heating only) and trying to install a smart Google thermostat that requires a c wire. I also got the Google nest power adapter where you put in your boiler system W/Y and R wires and the adapter gives you outputs with C, R and W/Y. My issues is that my boiler doesn’t have a c terminal so I don’t know where to plug the c wire that’s coming out of the adapter.

I couldn’t find any extra wires that might be the c wire (unused). I’m attaching pictures of what I have and I hope someone can help me please.

[[image: Google nest adaptor]

[image: boiler diagram]

[image: boiler wiring]

[image: detailed1]

[image: detalied2]

[image: detailed3]

[image: detailed4]

[image: wiring diagram for nest adaptor]

Comment: Do you have an external 24V transformer in your system?

Comment: I added more photos to show the wiring in the boiler, I’m not sure if this is the 24v adaptor. Also I tried the nest adaptor wiring diagram with a c wire transformer but it didn’t work!

Comment: does your boiler still turn on if you jumper terminals 6 and 7? Also, where does the wiring that connects to terminals 6 and 7 on your boiler go to?

Comment: 6 and 7 terminals are the ones that have the W and R wires that are connected to the thermostat and if I mix them up or use the adaptor diagram shown in the pictures, the furnace doesn’t turn on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your wiring matches the schematic shown on page 1-35 in the book? Remove the Nest power supply and adapter, then connect the wires as they originally were and confirm your old thermostat system still works properly.

Next try connecting R, W, and C functions as shown in the drawing below. If the colors of the wires don't match the colors here, attach labels to the wires. You can test the Nest thermostat right there at the boiler if you get a few feet of wire for making the temporary connection. It's OK to leave the old thermostats connected during this step so long as they're set low enough that they won't call for heat while you're working.

Once you have the Nest working at the boiler you can sort out whether there are enough conductors going from the boiler location to the desired thermostat location.

[image: annotated schematic]

Comment: Thank you Greg, I’m not sure how to add the wires as you showed in the diagram, I’m assuming that’s at the 24v transformer level? If yes, does that mean I should open the black box with a red Siemens label on it?

Answer (score 0):

### Your boiler is weird, but the black & red box has nothing to do with your problem

The first order of business is that you have a weird boiler that doesn't use a normal North American 24VAC control scheme; instead, it has a logic board that uses a *dry contact* control input.  This is fine when paired with an old-school electromechanical thermostat, but no good for electronic/"smart" thermostats like the Nest, as you have observed.

In addition, that black and red box is your boiler's gas valve, and has nothing to do with your issues, so *don't touch it!*  Instead, with the breaker for the boiler circuit OFF, you'll need to look for somewhere on the 120V circuit feeding the boiler you can tap power from.

### The diagram in the manual is your key

At this point, you'll need to provide a 4" square box with a 24VAC (Class 2) HVAC transformer mounted to it and wired into that circuit.  From the transformer, you'll need to run a 3 wire cable up to the Nest and a 2 wire cable down to the boiler; the red wire on the 3 wire cable goes to one transformer terminal, and the green wire on the 3 wire cable and the red wire on the 2 wire cable go to the other terminal on the transformer, while the two white wires get spliced together there with a wirenut.

At the boiler, then, you need to fit a 24VAC HVAC *fan relay*; one set of Normally Open (NO) contacts on the relay gets wired to terminals 6 and 7 on the boiler to provide the "dry contact" input it expects, and the coil terminals get connected to the incoming thermostat cable from the transformer location.  Finally, you can wire the thermostat up normally, without the "add-a-wire" gadget.